# Why plain constant still works in Composition API (Vue 3)?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

As stated on the official [documentation](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#setup), when  defining our "data" variable in the new composition api `setup` method, we must use `ref` or `reactive` in order to let Vue keep track of any change on that specific variable.

I am experimenting with reactivity and I have found a weird behavior.
Take this component this component as reference:

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>{{ awesomeState.txt }}</p>
    <p>{{ myConst }}</p>
    <button @click="operate">Test it</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import awesomeStore from "@/AwesomeStore";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const awesomeState = awesomeStore.getState();
    const myConst = "I'm a const"; // This should be const `myConst = ref('...');`
    return {
      awesomeState,
      myConst
    };
  },
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    operate() {
      this.myConst = 'Why this updates?';
      awesomeStore.changeText("yess!");
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

**AwesomeStore.ts**

```js
import { reactive, readonly, watch } from "vue";

export abstract class Store<T extends Record<string, any>> {
  protected state: T;

  constructor() {
    const data = this.data();
    this.state = reactive(data) as T;
    watch(() => this.state, (value) => {
      console.log(value); debugger;
    }, {deep: true});
  }

  protected abstract data(): T;

  public getState(): T {
    return readonly(this.state) as T;
  }
}

interface Test extends Object {
  txt: string;
}

class AwesomeClass extends Store<Test> {
  protected data(): Test {
    return {
      txt: "init"
    };
  }
  public changeText(msg: string) {
    this.state.txt = msg;
  }
}

export default new AwesomeClass();
```

When I click the button, the property `myConst` gets updated.
Aside I should not defined a method outside the boundaries of `setup()`, I do not get why this is happening.

Can anyone get a hint?

Thanks in advance,

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention, the exposed behavior only takes place if I try to modify the constant along side with the `awesomeStore.changeText` method:

```
operate() {
      this.myConst = 'Why this updates?';
      //awesomeStore.changeText("yess!"); <-- If commented, myConst do not update.
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things happening here that make it work

### 1) you're using a method instead of passing a function

You can use the standard Vue API `data:, methods:,etc...` or the composition API ie: `setup()`

Your example uses both. AFAIK, this is OK to do, however be aware that a method passed by `setup`  vs `methods` will behave differently. In a method, you will have access to the `this` object where `myConst` is mutable

```js
  methods: {
    operate() {
      this.myConst = 'Why this updates?'; // <=== access to mutable variable in `this` 
      awesomeStore.changeText("yess!");
    }
  }
```

if you were to use this example (below)  updating `myConst` would not work

```js
setup(){
  const myConst = "I'm a const"; // This should be const `myConst = ref('...');`
  // ...stuff...
  return {
    awesomeState,
    myConst,
    operate: ()=>{
      this.myConst = 'Why this updates?'; // <=== nope
      myConst = 'Why this updates?';      // <=== also nope
      awesomeStore.changeText("yess!");
    }
  }
}
```

### 2) You're updating ref and static

The other issue is that you're updating the static value followed by the ref. Changing ref will re-trigger rendering, at which point the static value would have changed

so if you remove the update through store, you should not be seeing the update happening any more

```js
  methods: {
    operate() {
      this.myConst = 'Why this updates?';
      // awesomeStore.changeText("yess!"); // <== no ref change, no update
    }
  }
```

here is a playground to test my "theory"

```js
const {
  createApp,
  ref,
} = Vue

createApp({
  el: '#app',
  setup() {
    let mystatic = 1
    const myref = ref(1)
    return {
      mystatic,
      myref,
      updateStatic: () => {
        mystatic++
      },
      updateRef: () => {
        myref.value++
      }
    }

  },
  methods: {
    updateStaticMethod() {
      this.mystatic++
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <li>Static: {{ mystatic }}</li>
  <li>Ref: {{ myref }}</li>
  <li><button @click="updateStatic">Static+</button> will not change. ever.</li>
  <li><button @click="updateStaticMethod">Static+(method)</button> will not update unless triggered elswhere</li>
  <li><button @click="updateRef">Ref+</button>update ref value (and force redraw)</li>
  <li><button @click="()=>{updateStaticMethod();updateRef();}">Both++</button> update both</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,
Thank you for your kind explanation.
I thought vue only looks value for object with "value" property in order to render it on the template.
I think, your point 2 is the key. `awesomeStore.changeText` re-render the template. Anyway, I also though Vue only render the parts of the DOM that changes.